# Регулярное выражение в Javascript. Поиск всех совпадений.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Всем привет,
Eсть такой код

```
<script>  
var str = 'Подъем в 06:50. Душ в 7-10. Зарядка в 7:30';  
var re = /\d\d[-:]\d\d/g;  
alert(str.match(re));  
</script>
```

В IE9 алерт выводит только первое совпадение - 06:50. Как вывести все совпадения?

Comment: @Irinkes Кнопка редактора 101010 форматирует код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var sample = 'Подъем в 06:50. Душ в 07-10. Зарядка в 07:30';  
var re = /\d\d[-:]\d\d/g;

var match = null;  
while (match = re.exec(sample)){
    alert(match);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в вашей строке 7-10 и 7:30 не имеют нуля в начале.

Comment: нули! спасибо, тогда код и без цикла работает

Answer (score 1):

Можно вместо `\d\d` поставить `\d{1,2}`

```
<script>  
var str = 'Подъем в 06:50. Душ в 7-10. Зарядка в 7:30';  
var re = /\d{1,2}[-:]\d\d/g;  
alert(str.match(re));  
</script>
```

Comment: круто, спасибо!

Comment: Тогда уж:

    /(?:0|[01]\d|2[0-3])[-:](?:0|[0-5]\d)/gm